# Spring integration File - reading the file by inbound channel adapter before it gets written

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am testing the [SI sample](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/file) and I am encountering the following issue.

My SI ver-1.0.4

For easier understanding I am pasting the contents below:

**fileCopyDemo-text.xml**

```
    <file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn"
                                  directory="file:${java.io.tmpdir}/spring-integration-samples/input" filename-pattern=".*\.xml">
        <integration:poller id="poller" >
            <integration:interval-trigger initial-delay="1000" interval="2000" fixed-rate="true"/>
        </integration:poller>
    </file:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <integration:service-activator input-channel="filesIn"
                                   output-channel="filesOut"
                                   ref="handler"/>

    <file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut"
                                   directory="file:${java.io.tmpdir}/spring-integration-samples/output"
                                   delete-source-files="true"/>

    <bean id="handler" class="org.springframework.integration.samples.filecopy.Handler"/>
```

**FileBasedCopyTest.java**

```
public class FileBasedFileCopyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/spring/integration/fileCopyDemo-file.xml");
    }
}
```

**Handler.java**

```
public class Handler {

    public File handleFile(File input) {
        System.out.println("Copying file: " + input.getAbsolutePath());
        return input;
    }
}
```

I have another java class which is creating a file into the input folder.

**Sample.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        String str = "SomeMoreTextIsHere";
        File newTextFile = new File("C:/Windows/Temp/spring-integration-samples/input/thetextfile.xml");

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
        fw.write(str);
        fw.close();

    } catch (IOException iox) {
        iox.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have run the FileBasedCopyTest and it is now listening to input folder.

**Question**
I am running the Sample.java file in debug mode and the momemt

> FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newTextFile);

is executed I am receiving the control in Handler.java, ideally I wanted to receive the control once the file is closed. How to handle this scenario?

PS : I have also read [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/1.0.x/spring-integration-reference/htmlsingle/spring-integration-reference.html#files) but not sure in this case how to handle here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem, regardless of whether you are using Spring Integration or not.

A common approach (used by SI in the outbound adapter) is to write the file with a temporary name (e.g. `foo.txt.writing`) and then rename it to `foo.txt` after it is written.

Comment: BTW, 1.0.4 is extremely old; the current release is 2.2.0.RELEASE.

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck with it, as my spring is v2.5.6 and currently no bandwidth to upgrade to 3.x Thanks for the alternative approach.